# jQuery REST PUT request doesn't work in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, jira

I just want to make a PUT request with jQuery in Jira.
I've tried it before with SoapUI and there it works, but in my JS file it's not working... It's always giving me an error back (alert with "no" in my case).

Here's my code:

```
var issueKey = this.JIRA.Issue.getIssueKey();
var username = "admin";
var password = "admin";
var encodedLoginData = btoa(username + ":" + password);

AJS.$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/jira/rest/api/2/issue/' + issueKey,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedLoginData },
    data: JSON.stringify('{"update":{"timetracking":[{"edit":{"originalEstimate":"4m","remainingEstimate":"3m"}}]}}'),
    success: function(response){ alert("yes"); },
    error: function(error){ alert("no"); }
});
```

As mentioned, the JSON data phrase works in SoapUI, also the login information and the base64 encryption. That's all correct.
But I can't find my fault... Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
PUT http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-3 400
XMLHttpRequest.send @   batch.js?devtoolbar=…logged-in=true:5461
send    @   batch.js?locale=en-US:197
ajax    @   batch.js?locale=en-US:191
calculate   @   batch.js?devtoolbar=…logged-in=true:5620
prepareCalculation  @   batch.js?devtoolbar=…logged-in=true:5620
(anonymous) @   batch.js?devtoolbar=…logged-in=true:5620
dispatch    @   batch.js?locale=en-US:104
h   @   batch.js?locale=en-US:96
trigger @   batch.js?locale=en-US:101
simulate    @   batch.js?locale=en-US:108
e   @   batch.js?locale=en-US:114
```

Comment: Would probably be better to do `alert(error)` instead of `alert("no")` to actually help you in what the error is.

Comment: I just edited my console output in my post.

When I do alert(error) it just says [object Object]

Comment: For future use, you can do `alert(JSON.stringify(error))` to display the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the parameter of your JSON.stringify shouldn't be a String. Try to save that into a variable and then make a JSON.stringify of that.

Take into account the result of JSON.stringify. For instance:

```
 JSON.stringify("{}"); //""{}""

 JSON.stringify({}); //"{}"
```

Now your code should be like this For example:

```
var issueKey = this.JIRA.Issue.getIssueKey();
var username = "admin";
var password = "admin";
var encodedLoginData = btoa(username + ":" + password);
var dataObject = {"update":{"timetracking":[{"edit":{"originalEstimate":"4m","remainingEstimate":"3m"}}]}};

AJS.$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/jira/rest/api/2/issue/' + issueKey,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedLoginData },
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
    success: function(response){ alert("yes"); },
    error: function(error){ alert("no"); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If this is an IIS server, you may need to disable WebDAV, as that grabs all PUT requests.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to be your error is that you're trying to stringify a string

```
data: JSON.stringify('{update...}')
```

Nowadays, you don't need jQuery to do HTTP in the browser. All modern browsers come with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) built in

```
const issueKey = this.JIRA.Issue.getIssueKey();
const username = "admin";
const password = "admin";
const encodedLoginData = btoa(username + ":" + password);

const body = {
  update: {
    timetracking: [{
      edit: {
        originalEstimate: "4m"
        remainingEstimate: "3m"
      }
    }]
  }
}

fetch(`/jira/rest/api/2/issue/${issueKey}`, {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedLoginData
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
  .then(response => alert('yes'))
  .catch(error => alert('no'));
```